# 'Element wise' notation for matrix-vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

Lets consider column vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and square matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

\begin{align}
\vec{y}&= B \vec{x} \\
\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} 
&= \begin{pmatrix} B_{11}  &\dots &B_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ B_{n1} & \dots &B_{nn}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

How can we express the vector-matrix product $\vec{y}= B \vec{x}$ in elementwise form?

Would this work
\begin{align}
y_i = \sum_{k=1} B_{ki} x_i
\end{align}

,where $i = 1, \dots , n$ , I assume $k = 1 \dots n$ as well?

Or would we represent this as $y_j = \sum_{k=1} B_{kj} x_j$ perhaps? I am that the B is a square matrix but I need to correct my notation for a case where B is not square.

Comment: It's $y_{j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} B_{jk} x_{k} $

Comment: Thank you @TomAriel .